# Hyphen (-) in XML element is becoming Underscore (_) when converting it into JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, file-conversion, activesupport

My XML elements have dates separated with hyphens and starting with an underscore to keep the XML valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <_2018-12-11>
    <USD>1.1379</USD>
    <JPY>128.75</JPY>
    <BGN>1.9558</BGN>
  </_2018-12-11>
  <_2018-12-10>
    <USD>1.1425</USD>
    <JPY>128.79</JPY>
    <BGN>1.9558</BGN>
  </_2018-12-10>
</root>
```

I converted the document into JSON using Nokogiri and Active Support. Here is the code:-

```
require 'json'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'
s = File.read('../data/currency_source.xml')
x = Nokogiri::XML(s)
newX = Hash.from_xml(x.to_s) #Even though I use Hash.from_xml(x).to_json, it throws an error "does not have a valid root"

puts JSON.pretty_generate(newX)
```

The above code prints information in Hash, the dates should be `_2018-12-11` but it is displaying as `_2018_12_11`.

When I only print the XML, it displays the date element correctly but not after converting it into JSON.

Is there something I can work around to get the Dates in the correct format i.e. separated by hyphens, not underscores?

P.S. I have also tried Crack and CobraVsMongoose. Crack is also producing the same undesired date format. However, CobraVsMongoose is maintaining the hyphens correctly but it is appending `$` symbol unnecessarily.

Comment: At which stage does this conversion happen? Is `x` what you expect? Does`newX` look like what you expect? Is it only after you call `pretty_generate` that things don't look the way you expect?

Comment: Hi @ChrisDutton, Printing `x` displays the parsed XML exactly as in the file with the correct date separated with Hyphens. It is when the conversion gets stored in `newX`. The `newX` shows Hash which is exactly I want but the dates are getting separated by underscores which is not desirable.

Comment: This would suggest the change is being made in `Hash#from_xml`. Not sure how to prevent this, but I see you figured out how to mitigate the issue. Good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conversion is explicitly done in the ActiveSupport code for `.from_xml`. From the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7373b5819a348b550af17e9a2cc8bb12de27942d/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions.rb#L162), the keys of the converted hash are normalized to remove dashes:

```rb
def normalize_keys(params)
  case params
  when Hash
    Hash[params.map { |k, v| [k.to_s.tr("-", "_"), normalize_keys(v)] } ]
  when Array
    params.map { |v| normalize_keys(v) }
  else
    params
  end
end
```

There is no comment to explain why this is necessary or desirable, and there is no option/switch to skip the normalization. One possible workaround would be to use a different delimiter (e.g., `_2018.12.10`) in your XML source keys and then convert them to dashes once you've got them safely into a Hash.

Comment: Hi @rmlockerd, Thanks, I figured out and about to post the answer. A huge thanks for confirming that I was on the right track. I just changed the underscore to a hyphen in the source and now I can see the correct date separated with Hyphens. Could you elaborate using a different delimiter in the XML source key?

Comment: I meant using something like `<_2018.12.10>` in your XML instead of dashes, since only dashes get converted. Period is probably your only option given the limited set of valid XML tag characters, and they have the virtue of being date-parsable (i.e., `Date.parse('2018.12.10')` will work).